# Making class work independently in this example

Tags: jquery, html, class

Working on some image rotating script and need to make the images rotate independently. I can't change the `file-preview-frame` class, it has to be the same (`file-preview-frame`), the reason is it's part of a large jquery file that has this class in it for all images.

HTML:

```
<div class="file-preview-frame" data-fileindex="0">
<img src="blob:https://somesite.com/someimage1">
</div>
<div class="file-preview-frame" data-fileindex="0">
<img src="blob:https://somesite.com/someimage2">
</div>
<div class="file-preview-frame" data-fileindex="0">
<img src="blob:https://somesite.com/someimage3">
</div>

....
```

Jquery image rotating script:

```
<script>

$(function() {
        var rotation = 0;
        $("#rright-<?php echo $i;?>").click(function() {
            rotation = (rotation -90) % 360;
            $(".file-preview-frame").css({'transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)'});

            if(rotation != 0){
                $(".file-preview-frame").css({});
            }else{
                $(".file-preview-frame").css({});
            }
            $('.rotation-<?php echo $i;?>').val(rotation);

        });

        $("#rleft-<?php echo $i;?>").click(function() {
            rotation = (rotation + 90) % 360;
            $(".file-preview-frame").css({'transform': 'rotate('+rotation+'deg)'});

            if(rotation != 0){
                $(".file-preview-frame").css({});
            }else{
                $(".file-preview-frame").css({});
            }
            $('.rotation-<?php echo $i;?>').val(rotation);

        });
    });

    </script>
```

Is there a way to make `file-preview-frame` work independently in this example? Spent several hours trying to make it work to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: create new `data` attribute for each image holds the degree value then update/set/get the value inside the click

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef I can't add anything to that jquery file. It's massive and I don't have enough experience to mess with it. Is there a way to change the rotate image jquery code to somehow make those divs act independently?